# How to set the position of the ASP.NET Ajax ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Can the position of the Ajax modalpopupextender be set either to an absolute or relative position on the page?

The default puts it at page center and I haven't found a way to override this.

I would like to position the popup close to the control that triggers it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are X and Y properties you can set with the latest version:

```
<AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ...otherproperties... 
     X="100" Y="300">
</AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```